# problem with a figure made of 2 center of simmetry

Tags: geometry, transformation

How can I show that if a figure in $\mathbb R^n$  or  has $2$ centers of symmetry, it has infinity in a mathematical way?

this is the defintion of center of simmetry in $\mathbb R^2$  = A point, within an object or figure, through which any straight line also passes through two points on the edge of the figure at the same distance from the centre but on opposite sides.

my consideration about this problem was to use the fact that it this figure has 2 centers of simmetry then it is similar to a line in $\mathbb R^2$ and the line has infinity centers . but how can i prove in a more solid way?

Comment: Do it for the line as you defined it. Use the definition - this is the mathematical proof.

Comment: @Moti ok so i wrote that such a figure would be infinity extended and so it has like a line infinity center . Is it correct so ? sorry for my bad english and for terms not appropriated

Comment: infinite plane as well